# Difficulty manipulating polygons using Turfjs and TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, polygon, turfjs

I've searched all over and haven't found an answer to this issue using Turfjs and Typescript.  I'm a beginner, so please forgive me if the answer is obvious. I'm trying to use turf.intersect to help me redraw a polygon so there is no longer an overlap. I probably have several mistakes in here, but the error message I get is on intersectionArray[i], saying:

> Argument of type 'Position[] | Position[][]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Position[]'.
> Type 'Position[][]' is not assignable to type 'Position[]'.
> Type 'Position[]' is not assignable to type 'Position'.
> Type 'Position' is not assignable to type 'number'.ts(2345)

Can anyone point me in the right direction? It looks like turf.intersect creates a polygon OR a multipolygon, but I cannot figure out how to work with the intersection after defining it.

```
function adjustedBoundaries(newAreaBoundaries:turf.Polygon,
  oldAreaBoundaries:turf.Polygon){
const intersection = turf.intersect(newAreaBoundaries, oldAreaBoundaries);
const intersectionArray = intersection?.geometry.coordinates;
  if(intersectionArray){
let oldAreaSpliceIndex = 0;
for(let i = 0; i < intersectionArray.length; i++){
  if(oldAreaBoundaries.coordinates.includes(intersectionArray[i])){
    intersectionArray.splice(i,1);
    oldAreaSpliceIndex = oldAreaBoundaries.coordinates.indexOf(intersectionArray[i]);
    oldAreaBoundaries.coordinates.splice(oldAreaSpliceIndex,1);
  }}
for(let i = 0; i < intersectionArray.length; i++){
  oldAreaBoundaries.coordinates.splice(oldAreaSpliceIndex,0,intersectionArray[i])
}
return oldAreaBoundaries;
}}
```

Comment: Update: I have learned that there is a turf method called "difference" that seems to do what I want very simply.  I still have other errors like the one above, though, so if anyone can help explain how to make the types match up I'd appreciate it!

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I've just come across the exact same issue!